# Eyeshot Document folder of samples

Tags: eyeshot

Please guide us to find source code of sample (https://www.devdept.com/support/samples). As mentioned in site there was no sample code in document folder in my machine after install the Eyeshot software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran the setup as admin, try checking the Document folder of the admin user.
Otherwise you can use this approach: https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011865579-Silent-Installation

Answer (score 0):

With Version "Eyeshot 2022" the samples are now in:

"C:\Program Files\devDept Software\Eyeshot Ultimate 2022\Samples".